# Next/Image + Firebase Storage 403 Error on read

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage, next-images

I'm trying to use Image from next/image and am using firebase storage to store the image files.

However I'm getting a 403 (forbidden) error when doing the following:

```
<Image src={profilePicURL} ...otherProps/>
```

I've tried using with `<img>` instead and the url works fine, so I don't think it's a url or permissions issue.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

next.config.js

```
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
   distDir: 'dist',
   images: {
      domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com'],
   },
   webpack(config) {
      // config stuff
      return config
   }
})
```

Firebase Storage Rules

```
match /profilePicture/{userID}/{fileName} {
   allow read: if request.auth != null;
   allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
}
```

Comment: If you check the Network tab in the dev tools, what's the image URL there when you get the 403 response?

Comment: The image URL I'm getting is : http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2F{projectID}.appspot.com%2Fo%2FprofilePicture%252FWIH42W6pAygibqHIOFKEPttlENh2%252Fpp.jpeg%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3Dc8e32c1f-48fb-41e9-9e05-5581408ff173&w=1920&q=75. If I paste the url into a new tab, I get "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid.

Comment: I temporarily got it working by  setting prop 'unoptimized' to true in <Image /> if in dev env. Is there another way around it though?

Answer (score 1):

same here.
403 error is Permission denied error. I accessed url `https://firebasestorage.googleapi.com...` that is the string after `url` query with browser and got 403 also.

This caused your Firebase Storage Rules is wrong. Next.js use next/image to optimize and cache image, so `request.auth` is always null.

So fix it.

```
match /profilePicture/{userID}/{fileName} {
   allow read: if true;
   allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
}
```